# Don't understand how to control css elements with jQuery css

Tags: jquery, css

I have some css inconsistencies on my site, and I think it is caused by jQuery css.

For example, I have this page: http://www.problemio.com - if you press on top-right create-account, the title link will appear in black color.

But if you go to this page: http://www.problemio.com/problems/categories.php and press sign-up on the top-right, the "log in" link will appear in blue.

What exactly is causing this, and how can I make sure that all these links appear in blue like in the categories.php page?

Comment: Doesn't for me (Firefox 8.0.1 on Lion OS X). What browser are you using?

Comment: @lolwut I am looking at it in Chrome

Comment: Best guess is that since you have multiple elements with the same id (login), changes apply to only one element which is not what you expect it to be. Always use unique ids.

Comment: @GeekedOut doesn't happen on my Chrome too.

Comment: Just to add to good answers here, the tools in Chrome's developer tools and Firebug can really help identify where CSS rules are coming from and identify these kind of issues pretty quickly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the first page, you load: http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/themes/black-tie/jquery-ui.css

On the second page, you load: http://jqueryui.com/themes/base/jquery.ui.all.css

These stylesheets define different styles.

Also, on the first page, you load your custom styles first, and the jQuery UI CSS second; you do the opposite on the second page. So on the first page, your styles are overwritten by the jQuery UI styles, while on the second page, your styles override the UI styles instead.

Answer (score 4):

The difference is the references in the  section. On first link you reference a jquery ui css that overrides the color of the login. On the other that css file is not linked. Have a look in firebug or press f12 in chrome(right click and choose inspect element and look at css)

Answer (score 2):

If you want consistency around your whole site, I recommend you have a base files for all your common css that is shared through out your site. The base.css is going to contain all the styles for your basic elements, and all the styles of how you want things to behave. In addition, if you have common JavaScript code in multiple files, I would also creating a shared base.js file that contains all basic javascript manipulation. This will allow you to have a consistent feel to the whole site.

Answer (score 1):

Your CSS file http://www.problemio.com/main.css on line 99 declares a gray color for the login link

```
.banner .site_login a {
    color: gray;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Change the color: gray; to color: blue; or any hex value you want and this "problem" will go away

Answer (score 1):

The inconsistence I see is that you are loading different CSS files !

one uses

```
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/themes/black-tie/jquery-ui.css
```

the other one uses

```
http://jqueryui.com/themes/base/jquery.ui.all.css
```

not really a jQuery UI issue...